# Preserving a local variable in a function run by a function

Tags: javascript, function, scope

So say I have a function like this:

```
function cookie(){
    var a = 5; 
    function cat(){return a}
    return cat()}

cookie() // 5
```

It works fine, it gets the variable a from the parent function. Now, when I define the cat function outside of cookie, it doesn't work like that

```
function cat(){return a}
function cookie(){
    var a = 5; 
    return cat()}

cookie() // "a is not defined" error message
```

So this does make sense, but I'm still wondering how I could pass the local variable from the function cookie, to the function cat.

**How do I go about making the local variable "a" from cookie to also be defined in cat, as a local variable?**

Comment: pass it as an argument, or use a scope common to both functions.

Comment: What? Would I have to change the arguments of cat? How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Variables are trapped in whatever scope you declare them in.

You can pass the *value* of the variable as a function argument just like any other.

```js
function cat(passed_a) {
  return passed_a;
}

function cookie() {
  var a = 5;
  return cat(a);
}

cookie();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean pass `a` as an argument into `cat`:

```
function cat(somevar){
    return somevar
} 
function cookie(){
    var a = 5; 
    return cat(a)
}

cookie()
```

What this does is declare `cat` function and takes an argument. Inside `cat`, the argument is returned. Now you can just pass `a` into the function and return it in `cookie`.

Comment: @CaptainCrunch I mean, you could hack something up, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I figured you might need to do something like this, but is there any way to bind a to cat through cookie, without editing cat?

Comment: Alrighty, I'll just stick with what you did.

Comment: You could of course get rid of `somevar`, just implicitly pass `a` and return `arguments[0]`. That will still modify `cat` though.

Comment: @CaptainCrunch well, you could do `function cat() { return this.a }` and then provide the value of `this` using something like `cat.call({a: 5})`. In this case, it's a bit roundabout and it's easier to pass an agument.

Comment: @vlaz agreed, but I believe the OP wants to return a without modifying cat which isn't possible

Comment: I understand that, however, there isn't another way of changing the context of a function - if `cat` doesn't have access to the variable, then it simply won't use it.